# SQL Join Multiple Subqueries - Count Open / Closed by Date

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to count all open tickets / closed tickets groups by date. Some dates will have 0 values for both but I'd still like to show the date. I feel like I'm close but can't seem to get the grouping correct, it's just giving a total.

```
DECLARE @DateFrom AS DATE = '11/16/2016'
DECLARE @DateTo AS DATE = GETDATE()

WITH DateRanges AS
(SELECT @DateFrom AS 'DateValue'
UNION ALL
SELECT DATEADD(DAY, 1, DateValue)
FROM DateRanges
WHERE DateValue < @DateTo)

SELECT CONVERT(varchar(10),DateValue, 101) AS "DateVal",

(SELECT 
COUNT(OPENDATE)
FROM DateRanges AS a
LEFT OUTER JOIN MAINTABLE
ON a.DateValue = convert(varchar(10), DATEADD(hh, DATEDIFF(HH, GetUTCDATE(), GETDATE()), OPENDATE), 101)
) AS opn,


(SELECT
COUNT(CLOSEDDATE)
FROM DateRanges AS b
LEFT OUTER JOIN MAINTABLE
ON b.DateValue = convert(varchar(10), DATEADD(hh, DATEDIFF(HH, GetUTCDATE(), GETDATE()), CLOSEDDATE), 101)
) AS cls 

FROM DateRanges
GROUP BY CONVERT(varchar(10),DateValue, 101)
```

This produces the following:

```
DateVal | opn | cls
11/16/2016 | 3 | 3
11/17/2016 | 3 | 3
11/18/2016 | 3 | 3
```

MainTable

```
ID  | OPENDATE   | CLOSEDDATE 
123 | 11/16/2016 | 11/16/2016
124 | 11/16/2016 | 11/18/2016
125 | 11/18/2016 | 11/18/2016
```

Expected Output

```
DateVal    | opn | cls
11/16/2016 | 2   | 1
11/17/2016 | 0   | 0
11/18/2016 | 1   | 2
```

Thank you for your help

Comment: What is the schema of the `MAINTABLE` ?

Comment: The MAINTABLE has OPENDATE, CLOSEDDATE, ID. It may look like this:
    ID | OPENDATE | CLOSEDDATE
    123 | 11/16/2016 | 11/18/2016

Comment: Nick what would help us more is if you showed a sample data in the MainTable and the expected output, because at the moment it is not clear what you are asking or what the data would be in the MainTable and and what is your expected output. We can see what you have got so far but no one knows what you expect to see for an acceptable output. Thanks

Comment: Sorry about that, I've edited my question with what I expect to see. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use your approach, but you need *correlated* subqueries, instead of totals:

```
WITH DateRanges AS (
      SELECT @DateFrom AS 'DateValue'
      UNION ALL
      SELECT DATEADD(DAY, 1, DateValue)
      FROM DateRanges
      WHERE DateValue < @DateTo
     )
SELECT CONVERT(varchar(10), DateValue, 101) AS "DateVal",
       (SELECT COUNT(mt.REQDATE)
        FROM MAINTABLE mt
        WHERE dr.DateValue = convert(varchar(10), DATEADD(hour, DATEDIFF(hour, GetUTCDATE(), GETDATE()), mt.OPENDATE), 101)
      ) AS opn,
      (SELECT COUNT(CLSDDATE)
       FROM MAINTABLE mt
       WHERE dr.DateValue = convert(varchar(10), DATEADD(hh, DATEDIFF(hour, GetUTCDATE(), GETDATE()), mt.CLOSEDDATE), 101)
      ) AS cls 
FROM DateRanges dr;
```

Also note that you should not need an aggregation in the outer query.

Comment: This worked! I had to make one slight tweak and put FROM MAINTABLE mt in the first subquery to match the second, but it worked perfectly! Thanks a lot, I appreciate it.